# Configuration to be done in cpanel php mailer Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

mailing function works fine on my localhost but when i upload my code in server cpanel it is throwing me the following error

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

if i telnet my domain server

```
220-xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com ESMTP Exim 4.69 #1 Fri, 30 Mar 2012 00:00:13 -050
0
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

Comment: may be the server is rejecting the connection on default port 25. did you check? try `telnel mailserver 25`

Comment: Is there configuration to be configured in cpanel

Comment: That depends upon the hosting provider. If they have closed port 25 they must have opened 465. You could use sendmail than SMTP.

Comment: can you post the output of `echo $this->email->print_debugger();`

Comment: If the same code was working, then its more likely that the problem is at the cpanel server. can you actually post your email config?

Comment: It's the same config used in my localhost and sorry broncha my laptop is in some problem will post it tomor ... Will post it tomor

Comment: 220 ******.com ESMTP this is what i am getting if i ping telnet mailserver 25

Comment: There can be multiple causes for the connection being rejected. Your host may have blocked any outgoing connection on port 25. Did you talk with your host if they block anything?

Comment: @Broncha i have just called them regarding this issue... will get back to u once i get the reply...... thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

As the script is not working on the server, check the firewall on the server.

SSH to server and telnet to mx record of the recipient domain.

telnet mail.receiver.com 25

Comment: Ssh to server ... How can I do it in my cpanel ... I am using windows ... And my receiver port is open